# Google Sheets - drag formula change page

Tags: google-sheets

I want to drag a formula to copy it down a column, but the formula includes a reference to a box on a different page in the document i.e. '1' etc. I want the page number to increase by 1 for each new box I drag to.

When I drag, the page number stays the same, instead of changing/ increasing by 1.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Row(1:1)` instead of `1`. For example try inserting and dragging down:

```
="see Page "&Row(1:1)
```

This could be extended to say:

```
="see Page "&Row(1:1)&" and Reference 33"
```

where autofill may not give the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

1. Manually fill at least 2 cells to set the pattern to be replicated.
2. Select those cells manually filled.
3. Do the drag down / drag right.